# PHP: create POSTER like Firefox plugin

Tags: php

I would like to create a PHP application like FIREFOX "Poster" plug-in [thisone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691/)

basically , I want to make a call to a url with post data, that will be the body of the URL.
(I want to send the contain of the body)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`curl`](http://php.net/curl).

Good luck with your project.